# How to create the subgroup of the files templates shared via IntelliJ IDEA plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

For example, in the **File and code templates -> other**, **JPA** group has two-level organizing:

[image]

I need similar 2-level organizing for my plugin, but have not found the example how to provide it.

Currently it is:

[image]

I want to change it to:

```
YDF/
├─ GUI Components
│  ├─ Badge.styl
│  ├─ Button.styl
│  ├─ ...
├─ Web pages/
│  ├─ RegularWebPage.pug
│  ├─ StaticPreviewAnywherePage.pug
│  ├─ ...
```

Also, currently I have the sole class **YDF_GUI_ComponentsTemplatesGroupFactory.kt**:

```kotlin
package com.yamato_daiwa.ydf.intellij_idea_plugin

import com.intellij.icons.AllIcons
import com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.FileTemplateDescriptor
import com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.FileTemplateGroupDescriptor
import com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.FileTemplateGroupDescriptorFactory


class YDF_GUI_ComponentsTemplatesGroupFactory : FileTemplateGroupDescriptorFactory {
  override fun getFileTemplatesDescriptor(): FileTemplateGroupDescriptor {

    val groupDescriptor = FileTemplateGroupDescriptor("YDF GUI Components", AllIcons.Nodes.Folder)

    /* [ Theory ] No ".ft" must be here. */
    groupDescriptor.addTemplate(FileTemplateDescriptor("Badge.styl"))

    return groupDescriptor

  }
}
```

I am asking this question after [has not been answered in the IDEs Support forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/12760054091794-How-to-create-the-subgroup-of-the-files-templates-shared-via-plugin-) for the 2 weeks.

Comment: Try to discuss this issue directly with IntelliJ Platform developers using other support channels. Please see  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-help.html